# Disabled=True on lightning:inputField shows different color for different fields

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, aura

I have an aura component, using a `lightning:recordEditForm`. The `lightning:inputField` is greyed out by using the attribute `disabled="true"`. Some of them have a different shade of grey, I tried to override the background-color of the `lightning:inputField` but not successful. Here is my sample code

```
<aura:component controller="CreateRequestController" implements="lightning:hasPageReference,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" >
<aura:html tag="style">
        .cuf-content {
            padding: 0 0rem !important;
        }
        .slds-p-around medium {
            padding : 0rem !important;        
        }
        .slds-modal__container{
            max-width: 70rem !important;
            width:60% !important;
        }  
        .slds-modal__content {
            <!-- overflow-y:scroll !important; --> 
            height:unset !important;
            max-height:unset !important;
        }
        .slds-modal__footer {
            width:100% !important;
            max-width: 70rem !important;
        }
        .slds-form-element__label {
            display: none;
        }
        .inputBackground {
            var(--slds-g-color-neutral-base-95, var(--lwc-colorBackgroundInputDisabled,rgb(243, 243, 243)));
        }
    </aura:html>
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName = "DV360_Partner_ID__c" aura:id = "dvform" onload="{!c.handleLoad}" onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" onsuccess = "{!c.handleSuccess}" onerror = "{!c.handleFailure}">
            <h3 class="slds-section__title slds-theme_shade">
                <span class="slds-truncate slds-p-horizontal_small" title="Section Title">Request Details</span>
            </h3>
            <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">

                    <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-3" fieldName="Payments_Entity__c" variant="default" aura:id="paymentsEntity" value="{!v.paymentEntity}"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-3" fieldName="Related_Advertiser__c" variant="default" aura:id="relatedAdv" value = "{!v.relatedAdv}"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-3 inputBackground" fieldName="Contract__c" variant="default" disabled="true" aura:id="contractId" value="{!v.contractId}"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-3" fieldName="Request_Type__c" variant="default" disabled="true" aura:id="reqType" value = "{!v.requestType}"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-3" fieldName="Umbrella_Product__c" disabled="true" variant="default" aura:id="umbrellaProduct" value="{!v.umbrellaProduct}"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-3" fieldName="Default_Google_Signing_Entity__c" disabled="true" variant="default" aura:id="signEntity" value = "{!v.defaultGoogleSigningEntity}"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-3" fieldName="Contract_Link__c" disabled="true" variant="default" aura:id="contractLink" value="{!v.contractLink}"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-3" fieldName="ownerId" variant="default" aura:id="ownerId"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout>
<footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" title="Cancel" type="text" onclick="{!c.handleCancel}"/>
                <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" aura:id="submitButton" title="Submit" type="submit"/>
            </footer>
            <lightning:spinner aura:id="spinner" variant="brand" alternativeText="Loading"/>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

Here is a screenshot of how it looks on the UI
[image]

I am not setting any background color? Could someone please provide any insight as to why this might happen. Some fields are grayed out differently. Ideally all of the grayed out fields should have the same background color. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem.
i updated the code inside the  tags by adding the following snippet
.slds-is-disabled {
background-color: #f3f3f3 !important;
}

I also added to the css file
.THIS input.uiInput--combobox[type=checkbox][disabled]
{
background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.THIS .slds-textarea[disabled]
{
background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
This worked for me. Thanks everyone!